# How to Seperate CSS for different pages so only required css properties load on specific pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a very big CSS file that contains more than 10,000 lines and 10 HTML pages. As of now, the CSS file is getting loaded on all the 10 pages.

Can any one suggest a way to divide the big CSS file into smaller pieces so, I can only load required CSS file for specific HTML page ?

I have tried using Chrome console to see the coverage and only 10% of the css file is in use for particular page. 
No Node js and No CSS Frameworks

Comment: split the large CSS file into smaller files and only link the smaller ones on pages that use them

Comment: how to separate the css files ?
How do we know, only these specific properties load on specific pages?
Its a very big file

Comment: this [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26467/refactoring-large-old-css-files/26468#26468) could be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Create more .css files and load them only in those HMTL files you need the CSS.
So for example make a file only for the slider in the index.html and link it also only in the index.html

TIPP: But also make sure that you make a global_style.css or styles.css for things like header and only connect the classes from the headers with this.

Comment: But what is the process to separate css properties ?

Comment: You have one CSS file. So you have sections in this file for example for the Slider.

Then you make a new slider.css file and copy the code from the first CSS file and paste it into the new one.

Now you only have to link the new .css into the .html file you need it.

Comment: There are more than 1000 html files. I dont wanna go to each and every file, search for css, separate, create a new css file and then link it to each HTML. 
Is there any easier method ?
it would be very helpful if there is one.
I tried using unused css and it works but I need that to do automatically, removing from global.css and applying it to a new css file
If there is none, I am trying to create an app which selects the html and css, then removes unused css creating a new file with used css

Thanks

Comment: Hm not really...you only can make the CSS file "smaler" with googles:
-> https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home